# Issue while installing wordpress in subdirectory due to SSL

Tags: subdomains, ssl

Here is the case, my [oracle fusion](https://iavinash.com) website was initially installed without SSL, last year using plugin “Really Simple SSL” plugin and following [this article](https://iavinash.com/free-ssl-make-website-https/) I changed it to HTTPS.

Now my hosting provider is providing free SSL, the problem is, if I install another wordpress in subdirectory https://iavinash.com/ask i cannot access wordpress backend. You can see it by navigating to https://iavinash.com/ask/wp-login.php

Note : I used Softaculous to install wordpress in subdirectory and selected https:// protocol.

Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after enabling SSL level to FULL on cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to install the new WP **without** SSL first and see if it works?

You can activate SSL later, as you did with your "main" website.